# How to Do Numpy Like Index Selection in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Let us use the following code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# encoding: utf-8
import numpy as np, tensorflow as tf # tf.__version__==2.7.0
sample_array=np.random.uniform(size=(2**10, 120, 20))
to_select=[5, 6, 9, 4]
sample_tensor=tf.convert_to_tensor(value=sample_array)

sample_array[:, :, to_select] # Works okay
sample_tensor[:, :, to_select] # TypeError. How to do this in tensor? 
tf.convert_to_tensor(value=sample_tensor.numpy()[:, :, to_select]) # Ugly workaround
```

Basically, how to get those elements as a tensor of appropriate dimension, just like numpy? I tried `tf.slice` and `tf.gather`, but cannot figure out the proper arguments to pass.

I can convert it to numpy and back, but not sure if it will sacrifice the operation's efficiency, and work as part of a custom training loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to use `tf.concat`, although it is probably not so efficient:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

sample_array = np.random.uniform(size=(2, 2, 20))
to_select = [5, 6, 9, 4]
sample_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(value = sample_array)
numpy_way = sample_array[:, :, to_select]
tf_way = tf.concat([tf.expand_dims(sample_array[:, :, to_select[i]], axis=-1) for i in tf.range(len(to_select))], axis=-1)
#tf_way = tf.concat([tf.expand_dims(sample_array[:, :, s], axis=-1) for s in to_select], axis=-1)

print(numpy_way)
print(tf_way)
```

```
[[[0.81208086 0.03873406 0.89959868 0.97896671]
  [0.57569184 0.33659472 0.32566287 0.58383079]]

 [[0.59984846 0.43405048 0.42366314 0.25505199]
  [0.16180442 0.5903358  0.21302399 0.86569914]]]
tf.Tensor(
[[[0.81208086 0.03873406 0.89959868 0.97896671]
  [0.57569184 0.33659472 0.32566287 0.58383079]]

 [[0.59984846 0.43405048 0.42366314 0.25505199]
  [0.16180442 0.5903358  0.21302399 0.86569914]]], shape=(2, 2, 4), dtype=float64)
```

A more complicated, but efficient solution would involve using `tf.meshgrid` and `tf.gather_nd`. Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70584240/how-to-use-tf-gather-nd-for-multi-dimensional-tensor/70584776#70584776) or this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70424291/how-to-use-tf-gather-similar-to-the-numpy-slicing/70424516#70424516) and finally [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69897393/get-values-from-tensor-using-argmax/69898146#69898146). Here is an example based on your question:

```py
to_select = tf.expand_dims(tf.constant([5, 6, 9, 4]), axis=0)
to_select_shape = tf.shape(to_select)
sample_tensor_shape = tf.shape(sample_tensor)
to_select = tf.expand_dims(tf.reshape(tf.tile(to_select, [1, to_select_shape[1]]), (sample_tensor_shape[0], sample_tensor_shape[0] * to_select_shape[1])), axis=-1)

ij = tf.stack(tf.meshgrid(
    tf.range(sample_tensor_shape[0], dtype=tf.int32), 
    tf.range(sample_tensor_shape[1], dtype=tf.int32),
                              indexing='ij'), axis=-1)

gather_indices = tf.concat([tf.repeat(ij, repeats=to_select_shape[1], axis=1), to_select], axis=-1)
gather_indices = tf.reshape(gather_indices, (to_select_shape[1], to_select_shape[1], 3))

result = tf.gather_nd(sample_tensor, gather_indices, batch_dims=0)
result = tf.reshape(result, (result.shape[0]//2, result.shape[0]//2, result.shape[1]))
```

```
tf.Tensor(
[[[0.81208086 0.03873406 0.89959868 0.97896671]
  [0.57569184 0.33659472 0.32566287 0.58383079]]

 [[0.59984846 0.43405048 0.42366314 0.25505199]
  [0.16180442 0.5903358  0.21302399 0.86569914]]], shape=(2, 2, 4), dtype=float64)
```

Comment: Thanks. This is similar to some solutions that I envisioned using APIs I know, but was hoping there could be some less convoluted, cleaner way for such a standard slicing operation. I am not sure if using a list will take advantage of tensor flow graph tracing, since the list construction is not native to tf. Is it more efficient than converting the tensor to numpy and back? By the way, you can directly use the elements of to_select in the for loop instead of the index.

Comment: Yes the loop is not so efficient. Updated answer.

Comment: Sorry, was too busy chasing stuffs, could not test it, but I accept the answer on faith, will test later. At least I got the idea and methods to look for. Thanks.